# Uncaught ReferenceError function() is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to make a confirm page using DOM, but my code still has an error.

Here is my code in my page **videoYoutube.asp** :

> JS :

```
function confirmSupp()
 {
  if (confirm(Voulez vous vraiment supprimer la video ? ))
  { 
    location.replace("VideoYoutubeSupp.asp");
  }
  else
  {  document.location.reload(true);  }
 }
```

> HTML :

```
<form id="testForm" method="post" action="videoYoutube.asp">
    <textarea id="lienYoutube" name="lienYoutube" rows="5" cols="33"></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" value="Valider">
    <div id="forA"><input type="button" value="Supprimer la video!" onclick="confirmSupp()"></div>
```

Comment: can you add the exact error.
On which line your getting that error.

Comment: `if (confirm(Voulez vous vraiment supprimer la video ? ))` - invalid syntax, you need a string.

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting in the question. Strings must be quoted. You got it right on line 5. Voting to close as off-topic as the problem is caused by a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap string of confirm dialog in quotes and write function in proper script tags. Below code seems to be working fine.

```
<body>
<form id="testForm" method="post" action="videoYoutube.asp">
<textarea id="lienYoutube" name="lienYoutube" rows="5" cols="33"></textarea> 
<input type="submit" value="Valider">
<div id="forA"><input type="button" value="Supprimer la video!" onclick="confirmSupp()"></div>
</body>

<script>
function confirmSupp()
 {
  if (confirm('Voulez vous vraiment supprimer la video ? '))
  { 
    location.replace("VideoYoutubeSupp.asp");
  }
  else
  {  document.location.reload(true);  }
 }  

</script>
```